# Problems With Hosting Websites With Google Drive

Tags: html, google-drive-api, web-hosting

I am currently making a website that I am hosting with Google Drive. I finished coding the login GUI of my website and I went to go test it. The html file is in a public folder. I got the document id of the folder and went to the URL that hosts my webpage. But it doesn't render my html. Instead, Google just displays my code. **How do I fix this?**

[Click here to link to my webpage](http://www.googledrive.com/host/0B7hKHDOEh8CCfm85R1VQSFRtR0JwOF9iUlhLM1VTZFBPSzB5dm1DaWw1WGFUQ2s2T3pubFU/Home.html)

Comment: Are you sure Google Drive can serve web files?   Google Drive see's a text document probably so it's showing you the contents of that text file (because from Drive's standpoint you want a file and/or it's contents).  I'm pretty sure all the cloud storage services don't want people using them as web servers and likely won't act as such.

Comment: I agree with LDMS, Google Drive isn't for servers.

Comment: yes I am sure. It is only possible because Google made it possible. Also, I just did the same exact thing earlier today (except with a different html file) and it worked. I don't know why it's not working now though.

Comment: Here is how to do it from google: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

Comment: Interesting. I assume you've followed all the steps from that link?

Comment: I also downloaded the file to make sure I didn't accidentally create a text file with .html as part of the title followed by .txt. But it downloaded as a .html file and it worked when I ran the file directly from my computer.

Comment: It actually worked for me, used your same html (I made a new HTML file and pasted in your html markup)

Comment: @LDMS when you clicked on the link, Google rendered my html?

Comment: Make sure your share ID is for the file itself, and not the containing folder (As I noticed it's the only file in the folder, so it may just be showing you that content by default)

Comment: @LDMS the file is in a shared folder so I assumed that all the sharing properties of the folder would be inherited by the file. Does this not work?

Comment: Apparently not? ALthough I tried doing the whole folder, and still showed me the rendered HTML when I clicked the file.  Why don't you try sharing just the file and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Interesting. @LDMS I just looked at the file properties on Google drive and it says that the file type is plain text. This might be my problem but now I am confused as to why it downloaded as an html file if on Google it's a plain text document.

Comment: Try creating a new HTML file, and pasting in your content like I did. At least then you know it has something to do with the file.  Although if you renamed it in Drive itself to .html, it doesn't actually change the file type which may be your issue?.

Comment: Yeah @LDMS it was really a .txt file.

Comment: Using Drive to host your website is a very bad idea. You have little control over how Drive maps mime types, and will face random quota issues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-hosted-css-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I looked at the properties of my file on Google Drive. It said that the file type was plain text. I downloaded the file and then uploaded it again as an html file. I got the document ID and tried again. This worked. The problem was that Google saw a plain text document so that's what it rendered. I just needed to change the file type of the file. I solved my problem although I cannot logically make sense of why my file downloaded as an html file if on Google Drive it was a plain text format.

Comment: Your file downloaded as text. When reuploaded probably google made a mimetype guess based on contents. Html is text. Just mimetype changes.